# for a parent Element, there are two child Elements. If .text() of child 1 matches, how to perfomr action on Child2

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

THe element is defined like this:

```
<div class ="frm-group'> 
   <label  class ="ng.binding" "Source Environment" ..... </label>
   <select class "ng-touched" ...... </select>
</div>
<div class ="frm-group'> 
   <label  class ="ng.binding" "Target Environment" ..... </label>
   <select class "ng-touched" ...... </select>
</div>
```

Div class is the parent class and "lable" and "select" class is the child class.

Problem Statement : I have to do the following :: If the Label.getText() matches with a string, then click on its respective select class and perform action.

I am capturing all the lable class elements in one WebElement LIst,

below is my code:

```
public void add inputs(){
// here I will get two elements int the list
   List<Webelement> labels = BrowserFactory.getdriver().findElements(By.xPath("//div/label[@class='ng.binding']")
// here I will get two elements related to select in the list
List<Webelement> selectDropdown= BrowserFactory.getdriver().findElements(By.xPath("//div/select[@class='ng-touched']")

for (Webelement label: labels )
{
if (label.getText().equals("Target Environment"))
{
// here I have to click the select(dropdown) of the matched label i.e Target Environement' select class
}
}
}
```

Help pelase..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following `xpath` which will find the `following-sibling` select

```
if (label.getText().equals("Target Environment"))
        {
           label.findElement(By.xpath("./following-sibling::select[1]")).click();
        }
```

Or

```
if (label.getText().equals("Target Environment"))
        {
           label.findElement(By.xpath("./following::select[1]")).click();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Kunduk, HAve an another question please. the select[1] , will it select the corresponding select , or the select which is in index 1 opsition. Should we give that 1 in select[1].

Comment: select[1] for the first select element after label tag.You can use select as well if you are using  `./following-sibling::select`

Comment: On the same note, how to apply following-sibling for a table kind of element struncture.

Comment: @Inspiron : I would suggest please post a new question with your relevant HTML and your expected output to provide you better solution.Please note SO is not about answering OP query it is more likely use for research purpose so that future reader can get help from that.Thanks.

Comment: sure. created an another thread.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61097750/for-a-parent-element-there-are-two-child-elements-if-text-of-child-1-matche

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211268/discussion-between-inspiron-and-kunduk).