# How to get the following-sibling element for a table type of structure

Tags: java, selenium

On the same note for a table kind of Element structure..as given below, how to apply the following-sibling . If the table hearder matches with the input string, enter the value in its corresponding text box.

```
<div class ="table-class">

<table class ="table-response">

<thead>

<tr>

<th class = "ng-binding" >testcase</th>

<th class="ng-binding"> environment</th>

<th class="ng-binding"> source folder</th>

</tr>

</thead>

<tbody>

<tr class ="ng-scope">

<td class="ng-input">

<input class="ng-scope-input" id='testcaseid">

</td>

<td class ="ng-input">

<input class="ng-scope-input" id="environmentid">

</td>

<td class ="ng-input">

<input class="ng-scope-input" id="source folder">

</td>

</tr>

</tbody>

</table>
```

TIn UI, this will be exactly in below format:

//Table Header

TestCAse ID   Environement  Source folder

```
public void add inputs(){
// here I will get two elements int the list
   List<Webelement> tlabels = BrowserFactory.getdriver().findElements(By.xPath("//div/table/thead/tr[@class='ng.binding']")
// here I will get two elements related to select in the list
List<Webelement> ltexts= BrowserFactory.getdriver().findElements(By.xPath("//div/table/tbody/tr/td/input[@class='ng-scope-input']")

for (Webelement label: tlabels )
{
if (label.getText().equals("TestCAse ID"))
{
// here I have to enter the string . //need help how we can use following-sibling for table type of structure.
}
}
}
```

with reference to :
[for a parent Element, there are two child Elements. If .text() of child 1 matches, how to perfomr action on Child2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61097750/for-a-parent-element-there-are-two-child-elements-if-text-of-child-1-matche)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to implement such scenario initialize number `i=1` and then while iterating increase the number to find the actual count of the element and pass that value while using 
`element.findElement(By.xpath("./following::input[" + i + "]"))`

**Code**:

```
List<WebElement> labels = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='table-response']//tr//th"));
        int i=1;
        for (WebElement label: labels )
        {
        if (label.getText().equals("environment"))
         {
           label.findElement(By.xpath("./following::input[" + i + "]")).sendKeys("Environment");
         }
         i=i+1;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your giudance, it worked in the expected way.. Thanks again.

Comment: could you please check this issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61145274/selenium-how-to-enter-data-in-to-tabular-format-frame-in-horizontal-way-in-ui